# How can I delete all open buffers with the MiniBufExplorer vim plugin?

Tags: vim, minibufexplorer

I'm using [fholgado's fork](https://github.com/fholgado/minibufexpl.vim) of the MiniBufExplorer plugin with Vim 7.4. I'd like to setup a map in my `.vimrc` to delete/close all open buffers, but nothing I've tried has worked.

Examples:

```
nmap <leader>bda :MBEbd 1,1000<cr>
nmap <leader>bda :1,1000 MBEbd<cr>
```

From the plugin's documentation:

```
:MBEbd[!] [N1] [N2] ...                                               *:MBEbd*
    Delete buffers but preserve the window that holding them.
    [N*] is the buffer's number or name to be deleted. If no [N*] is given,
    then current buffer will be deleted. Multiple buffers could be deleted
    at the same time.
```

Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have the plugin but this works for me for deleting buffers in default vim.

```
nmap <leader>bda :bd <C-a><^M>
```

`:bd`   - delete buffer

`<C-a>` - To autocomplete all matches

`^M`    - Enter

Comment: Yep, that was silly of me. I don't need to go through the plugin for that

Comment: You can also do this using `:bufdo`: `nnoremap <silent> <leader>b :silent bufdo bd<cr>` :)

Comment: "I don't need to go through the plugin for that" That's true for sooo many things in Vim.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Amit for your answer, I must change it in this way

```
nmap <leader>bda :bd <C-a> <CR>
```